# Using gstream with fifo

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to build two simple gstream pipelines such that:

- The transmitter side takes the input from the webcam and outputs it to a fifo
- The receiver side reads the fifo and plays the video (whatever the webcam is seeing).

I'm using the following command for the transmitter:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! videoconvert ! filesink location="video1.ts"
```

where video1.ts is fifo, created like this:

```
mkfifo video1.ts
```

and the following command from another terminal window

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="video1.ts" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I'm getting the following error in the receiver terminal:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Can someone help with the correct pipelines so that the video is played in the second terminal?

I searched Google and stackoverflow but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello KFUPM Electronics,

Like SeB said, you should specify the video format, resolution and framerate in both pipelines. This will solve the caps negotiation issue you are currently having. You can check the available cameras in your computer with the following command:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

And then you can check the supported resolutions, framerates and formats with this command:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext
```

In my case, my camera supports the resolution 640x480 with a framerate of 30fps and a video format of YUY. For this reason, my **sender** pipeline is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! "video/x-raw,format=I420,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! queue ! filesink location="video1.pipe"
```

In this pipeline, `videoconvert` helps me convert from the YUY2 video format of my camera to I420. Then, with the `queue` element we control lost frames.

From the **receiver** side, we can use the next pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="video1.pipe" ! queue ! "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=I420,framerate=30/1" ! rawvideoparse use-sink-caps=true ! autovideosink -v
```

As you can see above, we specify the same format, framerate and resolution. I recommend using `rawvideoparse` instead of `videoparse` since the latter is deprecated. This element ensures an output buffer has exactly one frame, you can check more information [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rawparse/rawvideoparse.html?gi-language=c).

Answer (score 0):

The receiver would have to know beforehand the video format, resolution and framerate, so these should be fixed on both sides.

**Sender:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! filesink location=video1.pipe
```

**Receiver:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video1.pipe ! videoparse format=4 framerate=30/1 width=640 height=480 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

See:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 videoparse
```

for other formats or options.

You may also try shmsink/shmsrc.